# How to return multiple arrays in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.8, render-to-response

I'm trying to return multiple arrays from my views file in Django. Here is my current attempt:

`views.py`:

```
qb =[] #some array with objects
qb1 =[] #some array with objects
qb2 = [] #some array with objects

return render_to_response('qb.html', {'qb' : qb}, {'qb1': qb1}, {'qb2' : 'qb2'})
```

And in my `templates\qb.html`, I have some tables set up like so:

```
     {% for p in qb %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{p.player.last_name}}</td>
            <td>{{p.player.first_name}}</td>

        </tr>
     {% endfor %}
     {% for p in qb1 %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{p.player.last_name}}</td>
            <td>{{p.player.first_name}}</td>

        </tr>
     {% endfor %}
     {% for p in qb2 %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{p.player.last_name}}</td>
            <td>{{p.player.first_name}}</td>

        </tr>
     {% endfor %}
```

Now what I had before (which worked) was just returning one array (namely `qb`) and then having one table which iterated over qb so I know my previous code was right and I just ended on taking two more arrays and then it crashed on the page saying:

> ```
> AttributeError at /qb/
> 'dict' object has no attribute 'push'
> ```

On the webpage with an error here:

```
return render_to_response('qb.html', {'qb' : qb}, {'qb1': qb1}, {'qb2' : 'qb2'})
```

So basically my question is how can I return multiple arrays and reference them in html file using Django?

Comment: The second argument of `render_to_response` should be a dictionary of the context. So your argument should be `render_to_response('qb.html', {'qb': qb, 'qb1': qb1, 'qb2': qb2})`.

Comment: @RodXavier beat me to the punch; I was about to say exactly what he just said.

Comment: @RodXavier thanks that was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @RodXavier please put you answer in an answer instead of in a comment on the question.